# Parameterization of a triangle in space

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

How can I find the parameterisation of a triangle with corners at

$$(1,0,0) \quad,\quad (0,1,0) \quad,\quad (0,0,1)$$

I want to have a function, $\textbf{r} (s,t)$, but I have no idea how to get there! Any tips?

Comment: Do you want the interior (with boundary) or just the boundary? Is the parametrization for a double/triple integral?

Comment: I guess it should be the whole triangle, i.e the interior with boundary, since I want to calculate the flux out of the surface!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** You have three points $A(1,0,0),B(0,1,0)$ and $C(0,0,1)$ that will allow you to build a triangle in ${\bf R}^{3}$, look at the following picture

[image]

Now, you are looking for a parameterisation of the surface built by that triangle, from what I understand from your comment. Here are some questions that may guide you in order to find *one parameterisation*:

- Is the surface you are looking for a plane?
- What is the equation of a plane?
- With three points can you find the equation of a plane?
- Do we have to be careful with the contours of the plane to fit the triangle? We may not want the whole plane that crosses the surface of that triangle, only the portion we need, this should be restricted by imposing conditions on the variables that are involved in the parametrisation.

*Perhaps an extra help:* you can construct the equation of a plane by knowing: a point belonging to the plane and a normal vector to the plane (thinking about the vector product may help).

Comment: Okay so I got the following parameterisation $ r(s,t) = (1,0,0) + t (1 , -1 ,0 ) + s(0 , -1 , 1)$ but when plotting it with $ 0<s<1 , 0<t<1$ I'm getting a parallellogram instead of a triangle! I guess the boundaries for $t, s$ are wrong! How should I think here?